How to change grafana datasource dynamically based on env
We have multiple databases running on different cloud environments,Our usecase is based on environment value we want to change datasource dynamically between AWS, AZURE and GCP.
We implemented the environment values to pass to grafana and created the environment variable to identify the cloud but now how can we change the datasource value between clouds ?
ENV variable:
{ "find": "terms", "field": "fields.env" }

For AWS we are using cloudwatch as datasource and for azure we are using azurecloud monitoring.
Adding sample queries to gather metrics from different datasources.
AWS:
{"alias":"","bucketAggs":[{"field":"@timestamp","id":"2","settings":{"interval":"auto"},"type":"date_histogram"}],"datasource":{"type":"cloudwatch","uid":"xxxxxx"},

Azure:
{"subscription":"xxxxxxxxx","queryType":"Azure Monitor","azureMonitor":{"resourceGroup":"xxxxxxxxx","resourceName":"xxxxxxxx","metricDefinition":"Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers","timeGrain":"auto","metricName":"cpu_percent","metricNamespace":"Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers","aggregation":"Average","dimensionFilters":[],"top":"10"}}


Don't think this is possible. Data source variable are very limited, and as far as I know changing between data sources of different type is not possible.
I'd consider creating three separate dashboards and providing quick links to switch between them. Yon even can pass variables between them.
